# Excel Power Query Sum Another Table Column Base on Current Table Column Cell Value

Tags: excel, powerquery

I have a table which have a different claim category hit by an individual. This table known as **MergeAll**:
[image]

Another table known as **Query1** and the **Category** column is there and I need help for the **Sum** column. *The figure in Sum column in the image is manually populated for illustration purpose.* 
For example row one of **Category** is **Check-in On Friday/saturday**, want the code able to go **MergeAll** table **Check-in On Friday/saturday** column to sum up and populate at the **Sum** column. 
[image]

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the MergeAll table,

add column, index column

right click index column, unpivot other columns

right click attribute column, group by, new column name: Total, Operation:Sum, Column:Value. OK

If you want you could then merge into the other table, but really thats already giving you what you want.

Sample code

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(Source, "Index", 0, 1),
#"Unpivoted Other Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(#"Added Index", {"Index"}, "Attribute", "Value"),
#"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Unpivoted Other Columns", {"Attribute"}, {{"Total", each List.Sum([Value]), type number}})
in #"Grouped Rows"
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, I initially thought it will be some kind of complex coding.